# Broken package ubuntu-keyring (Ubuntu 15.04 64 bit)

Tags: apt, gnupg, keyrings

I've tried to reinstall ubuntu-keyring, because I couldn't fix some GPG errors,

but the apt system has failed,

Now, I can't even upgrade or install anything.

I tried a lot of things such as :

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-keyring

sudo aptitude reinstall ubuntu-keyring

sudo dpkg-reconfigure ubuntu-keyring

sudo apt-get install --fix-broken
```

but it always ends with this kind of errors:

---

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  libdb5.3:i386
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove it.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up ubuntu-keyring (2012.05.19) ...
gpg: keyblock resource `/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/ubuntuhandbook1_ubuntu_apps.gpg': resource limit
gpg: keyblock resource `/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/videolan_ubuntu_stable-daily.gpg': resource limit
gpg: keyblock resource `/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/vlijm_ubuntu_lswitcher.gpg': resource limit
gpg: keyblock resource `/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/vthompson_ubuntu_ppa.gpg': resource limit
gpg: keyblock resource `/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/webupd8team_ubuntu_atom.gpg': resource limit
gpg: keyblock resource `/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/webupd8team_ubuntu_java.gpg': resource limit
gpg: keyblock resource `/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/webupd8team_ubuntu_y-ppa-manager.gpg': resource limit
gpg: key 437D05B5: "Ubuntu Archive Automatic Signing Key " not changed
gpg: key FBB75451: "Ubuntu CD Image Automatic Signing Key " not changed
gpg: key C0B21F32: "Ubuntu Archive Automatic Signing Key (2012) " not changed
gpg: key EFE21092: "Ubuntu CD Image Automatic Signing Key (2012) " not changed
gpg: Total number processed: 4
gpg:              unchanged: 4
dpkg: error processing package ubuntu-keyring (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 ubuntu-keyring
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

and when I tried dpkg-reconfigure a got this :

```
/usr/sbin/dpkg-reconfigure: ubuntu-keyring is broken or not fully installed
```

Comment: Do you have a large number of PPAs? or possible have added and removed many PPAs? How many keyrings are there in your /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/ directory? There are hints that the "resource limit" error may relate to that - see http://lists.gnupg.org/pipermail/gnupg-users/2013-December/048571.html

Comment: i think i have less than 20 PPAs (nomal usuage)but, in this case should i remove them or just disable them and try again !

Comment: thanks, i deleted some PPAs and i removed all gpg keys, i updated the system and reinstall the package, so now every thing looks good

Comment: Great! do you have time to write that up as an answer? I'm sure other people would find it useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any one who has the same problem, a big change this happen because of the big number of PPAs you have added, try to remove some of them and update the system.
Hope this can help.